# Разве правильно "кондукторА"?

Tags: фонетика

На одном форуме, посвященном русскому языку, я наткнулась на утверждение, что правильно говорить "кондукторА", а не "кондУкторы". Но, честно говоря, ударение "кондукторА" очень режет слух (как и прочие "крема", "офицера" и "слесаря"). Правы ли утверждающие, что ударение нужно ставить на А, а не на У и, если да, то почему?
Приведу даже это заявление насчет ударения:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Между двумя формами "кондУкторы и кондуктора" (работники транспорта) в последние десятилетия существовало нешуточное противостояние.

(1) Туда толпою пассажиры Текут с вокзального двора, Путейцы, сторожа, кассиры, Проводники, кондукторА (Б. Пастернак).

(2) Словарь Аванесова 1987 год: кондукторА и кондУкторы.

(3) Словарь Резниченко 2004 год: кондУкторы и кондукторА.

(3) Словарь Резниченко 2009 год: кондукторА и кондУкторы.

(4) Грамота.ру, 2014 год: кондукторА победили!

КондукторА - разговорная форма, кондУкторы - книжная форма. Возможно на выбор разговорного варианта в качестве единственного повлияло существование "кондуктора" в значении технической детали (кондУктор - кондУкторы). С другой стороны, есть же у нас профессорА и директорА, хотя и рЕкторы тоже есть.

Comment: @София, Грамота.ру, если брать орфоэпический словарь - это "Русское словесное ударение.Словарь нарицательных имён". Автор М. В. Зарва. Оцифровано в 2001-2002 гг., а не в 2014-м. 

Так как словарь Зарвы предназначен прежде всего для работников радио и телевидения, то вариантов с двумя ударениями там нет. Даже классический пример "твОрог-творОг" представлен в данном словаре только во втором варианте.